# operation based on alert box

Tags: flex3

is it any possible to create operation based on the alert box(like yes or no option)?
Thank's in advance...

Comment: Dude, you've asked 19 questions and had 17 of them answered, but you have not marked a single one accepted. What gives? If the answer solved your issue it's courtesy on Stack Overflow to accept it by clicking the checkmark next to the answer. People are not going to want to answer your questions in the future if you are not giving them the credit they deserve for it. plus marking answers as accepted keeps the community bot from bumping them back to the top of the list needlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to fire off a function based on the users decision? If so there is a closeHandler as part of the Alert.show constructor that you can tell it what function to run when the alert box closes.

```
Alert.show("My Message", "Alert Box Title", (Alert.YES | Alert.NO), null, alertCloseHandler);

private function alertCloseHandler(event:CloseEvent){
  if(event.detail == Alert.YES){
    //code if they clicked yes
  }
}
```